Можно ли перепрыгнуть с одной строки кода на другую?
Мне нужно, чтобы после выполнения определённой части кода программа возвращалась назад на определённую строку. Что-то наподобие этого:
import sys
question = "сколько лап у собаки?"
ansewer = "4"
ansewered = input(question, "Ответ: ")
if ansewered != ansewer:
    print("Неправильно! Хотите попробовать ещё раз?")
    retry = input("Да/нет: ")
    if retry == "да":
           #и тут то что отвечает за то что-бы вернуло к 3 строке
    if retry != "да":
               sys.exit()

Я уже пробовал goto, но, по-моему, сделал что-то не так.

Воспользуйтесь циклом while

В питоне нет goto, хотя я тут как-то писал самописный goto в каком-то ответе на какой-то вопрос )

Не надо менять название вопроса. Галочки на правильный ответ достаточно :-)

Обычный "бесконечный цикл" с прерыванием через break:
import sys

question = "сколько лап у собаки?"
ansewer = "4"
while True:
    ansewered = input(question, "Ответ: ")
    if ansewered != ansewer:
        print("Неправильно! Хотите попробовать ещё раз?")
        retry = input("Да/нет: ")
        if retry.lower() != "да":
            break

